does video_player support multivariant resolutions in a master.m3u8 manifest file in ios?
I've been out a video streaming feature in a flutter app. i generate mutliple resolution files and have at least to different playlists. both are listed in a master.m3u8 file however i can't seem to get this file to load the at all. either playlist works perfectly fine and streams the video content but it appears that video_player package doesn't handle this kind of file. I would just like to know for clarity if thats correct or if there are alternative players that would manage this issue in flutter.
final masterPlaylistContent = ''' #EXTM3U #EXT-X-VERSION:10 #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=2000000,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2" ${fixedPlaylistUrls['${name}_0_playlist.m3u8']} #EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=800000,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2" ${fixedPlaylistUrls['${name}_1_playlist.m3u8']} ''';
example code above of the master.m3u8 file

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

did you find any solution???

the short answer is yes it works. but i couldn't figure out the format. i ended up using gemini ai to configure the master file for me and it worked. @Nurullah Sadekin

oh find it out by download and then decoding the file . it returnes multiple m3u8 file with availbale resolution
